# Flexible content requirements for Matrix

Tags: matrix, plugins, field

I’m attempting to setup a site with only a couple of templates and having a LOT of Matrix fields so the client can build content out of component based content, making it super flexible (hopefully).

I'm using Matrix Table Field Types for various items but what I really need to do is have the ability to have other types of content within the Table, other than just 'single-line text', 'multi-line text', 'number' or 'checkbox'.

Does anyone know any way to do this or of there are maybe any plugins which would solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If these Matrix fields are going to have a lot of fields then I'd recommend taking a look [Pimp my Matrix](http://plugins.supercooldesign.co.uk/plugin/pimp-my-matrix) to keep them well organised.

If you're wanting to make your Tables more powerful and have more field types check out [SuperTable](https://github.com/engram-design/SuperTable).

Comment: Thanks, someone else just recommended on the Slack channel too. Looks great, though getting confused with the template for using it within a Matrix field.